# I need to enclose this porch. What are the things that I can expect to have to do?

Tags: renovation, porch

So the plan is to remove the planter, build a wall on the side where the planter is Relocate the entrance door. Practically this turns the porch into a entrance hallway. 
The porch has light on the ceiling, controlled from inside. The porch is built on a concrete slab that you can see in the picture. I am inclined to believe that it has a proper foundation and it won't need to rebuild it.
I will have to remove the tin ceiling of the porch and install drywall and insulation there. I might choose to leave the brick look of the wall adjacent to the garage (left side of the picture) and insulate that section of the wall from inside the garage.

What am I missing or overlooking. For those of you who want to make references to the code this is in Ontario Canada

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from local code, building the walls with proper header(s) for door(s)/window(s), electrical outlets and switches, you are on the right path. Big issue I see is the concrete slab. That will be a heat loss issue. You could potentially build it up with some insulation inside the cavity, but you might be limited in height to have it the same as the current room floor.

Comment: I could raise the entire floor. Behind that door there small landing area for. stairs t,he basement has above the grade windows. Form that area I have on one side (left) stairs going into basement and on the right side stairs going up on the main floor